# Weak preferences and negative transitivity

Tags: preferences, choice-theory, proof, proof-reference

Let  $ \succ $ be a binary relationship on the set $X$ such that, given any $ x, y, z\in X $, if $x\succ y$:

1. (Asymmetry):  $\neg(y\succ x)$,
2. (Negative transitivity): $(x\succ z) \vee (z\succ y)$.

Let us define the abbreviations:

3. $x\succeq y \;:=\; \neg(y\succ x)  $,
4. $x \sim y \;:=\; x\succeq y\; \wedge \;y \succeq x$.

As usual, the relations $\succ, \succeq, \sim$ denote strong preference, weak preference, and  indifference.

Intuition suggests that I can conclude:
$$x\succeq y \; \leftrightarrow \;(x\succ y\; \vee \;x\sim y) $$

If so, how can I derive it formally? Any useful references?

Comment: Is the relation $\succeq$ complete?

Comment: @Giskard:     The definitions above are taken from Föllmer, Schied, Stochastic Finance, where it is stated that $\succeq$ completeness is implied by the asymmetry and the negative transitivity of $\succ$.

Comment: Thanks for the source. Remark 2.3. claims that these properties are equivalent to $\succeq$ being transitive and complete. Can you then not take the usual $\succeq$ route to prove your intuitited statement?

Comment: @Giskard: Well, usually  $x\succ y\; \vee \;x\sim y$ is taken as the definition of $ x\succeq y$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably it can be done easier if you do both steps separately ($\implies$ and $\impliedby$), but here is a proof that does both at the same time:
\begin{align*}
&x\succ y \vee x\sim y\\
\iff\;& x \succ y \vee (x\succeq y \wedge y \succeq x)  & \text{Definition of $\sim$}   \\
\iff\;& (x \succ y \vee x\succeq y) \wedge (x \succ y \vee y \succeq x)& \text{Distributivity}\\
\iff\;& [x \succ y \vee \neg( y \succ x)] \wedge [x \succ y \vee \neg(x\succ y)]& \text{Definition  of $\succeq$}\\
\iff\;& x \succ y \vee \neg( y \succ x)& \text{LEM}\\
\iff\;& [x \succ y \vee \neg( y \succ x)] \wedge[x \succ y \to \neg( y \succ x)]& \text{Asymmetry}\\
\iff\;& [x \succ y \vee \neg( y \succ x)] \wedge[\neg(x \succ y) \vee \neg( y \succ x)]& \text{Definition of $\to$}\\
\iff\;& [x \succ y \wedge \neg(x \succ y)] \vee \neg( y \succ x)& \text{Distributivity}\\
\iff\;& \neg( y \succ x)& \text{Contradiction}\\
\iff\;& x \succeq y& \text{Definition  of $\succeq$}\\
\end{align*}

Negative transitivity seems to not be a necessary condition for this proposition.